# Is there a way to group several torrents for easier torrent list management?

Tags: utorrent

By default, the main window has each torrent listed individually. I'd like to place some torrents in a "folder" (imagine collapsing a branch in a tree view list). Is there a way to group torrents and collapse them in the main torrent list?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  Label whichever torrent(s) you'd like to sort or group.  You can then add the "Label" column and sort on that column.  Even better, in the side-bar, there will be a list of your labels which you can then select and which will then show only those torrents with that selected label (kinda like selecting a folder in Windows).